# Есть ли в mongoengine метод before_save или подобный

Tags: mongodb, python-3.5, pymongo, mongoengine

Недавно стал пользоваться mongoengine, никак не могу нагуглить есть ли там такие методы в моделях как beforeSave(), beforeUpdate() и т.д.

Нужно некоторые поля заполнять по-дефолту для всех инстансов, но при этом не статическими данными. Например если делать так:

```
class Subject(DynamicDocument):
    meta = { 'collection': 'subjects' }
    created_at = IntField(default=int(time.time()))
```

то в created_at будет всегда находиться один и тот же timestamp, он проинициализируется сразу при импорте класса, и при создании инстанса останется таким-же. Если делать так:

```
class Subject(DynamicDocument):
    meta = { 'collection': 'subjects' }
    created_at = IntField()

    def save(self):
        self.created_at = int(time.time())
        self.save() # самого себя вызываем - чушь собачья
```

и даже если в классе сделать некий условный `my_save()` который проставляет значения и в конце вызывает `self.save()` то всё равно это во-первых костыль, а во-вторых это надо везде менять `save()` на `my_save()` и вообще не по фен-шую. Существует в mongoengine возмощность задать в модели некие методы, которы будут вызываться перед созданием, перед сохранением, перед обновлением?

Есть ещё такой метод `clean()` он делает почти то, что нужно:

```
class Subject(DynamicDocument):
    meta = { 'collection': 'subjects' }
    created_at = IntField()

    def clean(self):
        self.created_at = int(time.time())
```

НО: как быть с апдейтом? Если мне например `updated_at` нужно точно так-же проставить? Прямо в коде проверять наличие `created_at` и если она есть и если меньше текущей то создаём `updated_at`? Как-то криво. Хочется элегантнее, средствами mongoengine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [здесь](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html#attaching-events) в принципе описано решение проблемы